# Boolean expression problem with Logic Friday

Tags: boolean-algebra

I don't know if I'm doing this wrong, but [Logic Friday](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer#Logic_Friday)'s minimized form for this two equations is one. I tried with a K-map and is not.

F= ABC + ABD + ACD + B'C'D + ACD' + A'B'D

(my result is AD+B'D+AC)

G= BC + A'B'C'+BC'+A'C

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: If I'm doing it wrong or I should not trust Logic Friday

Comment: Draw a truth table for all three expressions and compare.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did and my work is right. Do you know any other software like Logic Friday?

Comment: This question is a mess ... " .. minimized form for this two equations ..."  what two equations?  " ... is one ..." is one what? one equation, or the identity 1 ? Are the two equations F & G? if so what is the result from Logic Friday? Is G the result? then what is the other equation? it is nonsense right now.

Comment: @DaveTweed The link is wrong

Comment: @BlairFonville: Thanks. It looks like [Sontrak](http://www.sontrak.com/) has gone out of business. I've updated the link to point to the Wikipedia entry for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha appears to give the right answer.  I used their [Boolean Algebra widget](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=4c86f3bbcab249f879058d1825887571&title=Boolean%20Algebra%20Calculator&theme=green) since for some reason it didn't recognize the same formula entered on their [main page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) as a Boolean algebra expression.

I entered:

(A and B and C) or (A and B and D) or (A and C and D) or (not B and not C and D) or (A and C and not D) or (not A and not B and D)

and it returned:

[image]

Interesting that they ask you to enter equations using AND, OR, NOT, XOR, NAND, NOR etc. but the results are displayed as shown above.  Anyhow the first result (DNF, which stands for  disjunctive normal form) matches your result.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with Logic Friday but the syntax is tricky.
Try

F = A B C + A B D + A C D + B' C' D + A C D' + A' B' D;

(with spaces between operands) and you will receive

F = A C  + A D + B' D;

as minimization. Same thing for G.